# PrimeVue Datatable: how to use different primeVue icon for sort control

Tags: primevue

Instead of

pi-sort-alt,
pi-sort-amount-up-alt,
pi-sort-amount-down

would like to use

pi-sort,
pi-sort-up,
pi-sort-down

I think I can replace the content using css but wanted to check if there is a better way.

Comment: There seems to be a header slot in column (`<Column><template #header>...</template></Column>`) but it's not working properly for me. Might be an idea for a feature request... https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues